# netns problem about connect to an ap

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ffmpeg

I have some question about netns, that i dont understand.

I create the namespace

```
ip netns add test
```

then add the wireless interface

```
ip link set wlx18d6c713f8b1 netns test
```

when use **iwconfig**

```
root@localpc:~# ip netns exec test iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx18d6c713f8b1  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
      Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

it said i have one interface, **BUT** nmcli cant find in the namespace

```
root@localpc:~# ip netns exec test nmcli device
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION         
enxd481d7246891  ethernet  connected    Wired connection 2 
wlp2s0           wifi      connected    myap             
enp0s31f6        ethernet  unavailable  --                 
lo               loopback  unmanaged    --
```

so where is my setted wireless interface?

i need to connect to an AP within the namespace.

Otherwise, i have a project that i have to run a python program with ffplayer on a specified wireless interface, so i anybody have a good idea about this, i am gladly read it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nmcli communicates with Network Manager which is running in the initial network namespace.

You may need another instance of Network Manager and dbus, with some additional mount to keep them separate from the instances running in the initial network namespace. `ip ns exec` creates a new mount namespace for you.